# Click not working after scrolling RecyclerView

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

i am new to app developer and want to make app with json api and WordPress as backend. i can fetch the posts and it works fine untill first 10 posts, when i click on each post i can see the post detail as well, but on 11th post or when scroll to next page, click doesn't work and app crashes, the error i got is this:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 10
```

i have searched lot on google but did not get any solution..

this is my code to load more posts

```
 recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                isScrolling = true;

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            currentItems = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
            totalItems = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            scrolledItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

            if (isScrolling = (currentItems + scrolledItems == totalItems)) {
                isScrolling = false;
                yourURL = "https://punjabidharti.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?categories=4514&per_page=10" + "&page=" + pageNo++;

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (mListPost != null) {
                    getRetrofit();

                } else {

                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

            }

        }
    });
```

this is the code to get posts..

```
 call.enqueue(new Callback<List<WPPost>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<WPPost>> call, Response<List<WPPost>> response) {
            Log.e("mainactivyt", " response "+ response.body());
            mListPost = response.body();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                for (int i = 0; i < response.body().size(); i++) {
                    Log.e("main ", " title " + response.body().get(i).getTitle().getRendered() + " " +
                            response.body().get(i).getId());
                    String tempdetails = response.body().get(i).getExcerpt().getRendered().toString();
                    tempdetails = tempdetails.replace("<p>", "");
                    tempdetails = tempdetails.replace("</p>", "");
                    tempdetails = tempdetails.replace("[&hellip;]", "");
                    list.add(new Model(Model.IMAGE_TYPE, response.body().get(i).getTitle().getRendered(),
                            tempdetails,
                            response.body().get(i).getLinks().getWpFeaturedmedia().get(0).getHref()));
                }


            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<WPPost>> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
```

and this is the onclick method in adapter

```
private ArrayList<Model> dataset;
    private Context mContext;

  
    public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<Model> mlist, Context context) {
        this.dataset = mlist;
        this.mContext = context;

    }

     @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final Model object = dataset.get(position);
        ( (ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).title.setText(object.title);
        ( (ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).subtitle.setText(object.subtitle);


        ( (ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent (mContext, PostDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra ("itemPosition", position);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        ( (ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).subtitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent (mContext, PostDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra ("itemPosition", position);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataset.size();
    }



    }
```

please help ....

Comment: IndexOutOfBoundsException means an index of your list is out of range. Your list only have 10 items but you are trying to access 11th item (0 also count) . Comment all the code and after scrolling  just check your list size  see if the size getting updated or not .

Comment: Can you show the complete code which you have written in your adapter file? Something related to itemCount has an issue. IndexOutOfBoundException is exactly what @HimanshiThakur explained.

Comment: please check my updated code @AkshayShenoy

Comment: please can you tell me how to do that ? i have updated the code please check @HimanshiThakur

Comment: i have updated the code please check @AkshayShenoy